# Context menu and ToggleButton in ListView row

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, togglebutton

I have got a `ListView`, whose a `TextView` a `ToogleButton`. Now I have to implement a context menu for my `ListView`. But if the toggle buttons are visible, context menu won't show up. `onListItemClick` doesn't work, either. Why? [image]

Comment: context menu will work on onLongClick listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ChiragRaval, I have found the solution.

`android:focusable="false"` for the `ToggleButton` is what I need. Now both the `ToggleButton`s and the context menu work.